Laravel rendering duplicated classes. How to fix it?
I'm new to Laravel.
I have the following snippet in my navigation.blade.php:
<div class="space-x-8 text-xl sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
    <x-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')" >
        {{ __('Licenses') }}
    </x-nav-link>
    <!-- some more links -->
</div>

And this snippet is being rendered like this:
<div class="space-x-8 text-xl sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
    <a class="inline-flex 
              items-center 
              px-1 
              pt-1 
              border-b-2 
              border-indigo-400 
/* issue-> */ text-sm 
              font-medium 
              leading-5 
              text-gray-900 
              focus:outline-none 
              focus:border-indigo-700 
              transition 
              duration-150 
              ease-in-out 
/* issue-> */ text-base"
       href="https://my.domain/licenses">
        Licenses
    </a>
</div>

I marked the problematic points with /* issue-> */.
I tried looking for the base renderer that convert x-nav-link to an HTML <a href="...">...</a> without success.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

<x-nav-link> points to a Laravel view component, which by default should reside in:
app/View/Components/NavLink.php

it has an associated view file in:
resources/views/components/nav-link.blade.php

Either one of those files contains the logic that adds text-sm and/or text-base classes.
